# Eventbrite - Getting past events

Tags: eventbrite

I'm using eventbrite.com, and I'm trying use the rest API to get all the previous events for my user (organizer in eventbrite). I am expecting to get events that have occurred in the past.

I'm using the following url:

```
https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?organizer={MyOrganizerName}&app_key={MyAppKey}&date=past
```

However, I get nothing returned. ever. I am sure that have some events that happened in the past.
I am successfully getting events in the future. so there's nothing wrong with my client\app key\spelling\whatever.

Answer (score 2):

With the newer [Eventbrite APIv3](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/) the endpoint changed to `/users/me/owned_events` The API comes with an API Explorer, which lets you see detailed debugging information for any endpoint just by going to it in a web browser.

Paste this url with your token id into your browser to get all past events:

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?token=YOURTOKENID

The result is a paginated response of all the events your user account is organizing.

Answer (score 0):

The [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) method is meant to return publicly available information about upcoming events only.

Try [user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/) instead:

```
https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/user_list_events?app_key={YOUR_APP_KEY}&user_key={YOUR_USER_KEY}&event_statuses=ended
```

You also have the option of creating an [Organizer Profile Page](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/), allowing you to group similar events together.  The [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/) API call may be useful for folks who are using that feature.

Comment: I see how your solution is more correct, but it is not returning any events as well..

Comment: did you include your app_key and user_key?

Comment: included the app key. I am trying to access it anonymously but all the event are public.

Comment: The [user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/) API call requires either a user_key (or another valid user authentication token), or a 'user' parameter that is set to the email address of the event owner.

The [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/) call returns this information without requiring any private authentication tokens. But, a valid organizer_id must be supplied instead.